# How can I add learn more text on a card in HTML when I hover over the card element

Tags: html, css

How to create a hover effect in CSS that displays new text alongside

I created a card using  HTML  and give it a hover CSS effect yet am unable to see the new text like learn more that will show after I hover over the elements.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done.

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
    
.myDIV:hover + .hide {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>Display an Element on Hover</h2>

<div class="myDIV">Hover over me.</div>
<div class="hide">I am shown when someone hovers over the div above.</div>
```